# Ways to Intentionally Create Catastrophic Forgetting in Reinforcement Learning? [Unity ML-Agents PPO]

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am working on a reinforcement learning project through Unity's ML-Agents, and I would like to intentionally create/cause catastrophic forgetting to happen for my agent. I wonder if there are ways to "implement" the catastrophic forgetting, or is it just something that simply happens by chance? I am relatively new to ML and any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Currently, I plan to set up different training tasks to train my agent sequentially. But I do wonder if there are ways to fine-tune the config file and other setups to achieve the forgetting.

Comment: Do Unity ML agents have a Q-table property? Usually, simpler RL uses a Q-function / policy to learn to maximize reward, if you reset the Q values to initial (full zeros) or policy to equal probabilities then that'd do the trick. Pretty sure there should be a method for resetting one of the two.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.